# Running head but no page number on certain page with float

Tags: floats, koma-script, page-numbering, scrlayer-scrpage, pagestyle

I want to suppress the page number on the landing page of a certain float -- but the running head should appear there.

My MWE shows, how to suppress page number *and* running head `thisfloatpagestyle{empty}`. But I want the running head to be there in the section entitled “Problem”.

Am I placing `\ofoot` in the wrong place? Or is there a cleaner solution?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{TestHeadingsFigure}
\author{Test}
\date{September 2020}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{test}
\section{Everything is ok}

%Float appears on whole page, no running head and no page number (works)
\begin{figure}[p]
    \thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
    \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{Problem}
\vfill
%Float appears on lower part of page, runnig head should exist, but page number should not exist (but it does!, so it's not working)
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \ofoot{}
    \thisfloatpagestyle{scrheadings}
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{It's ok}

%Float should be a normal float, runnig head and page number as on normal pages (works)
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: The page number with red circle shouldn’t be there]